# Running Android unit test outside of gradle build tool - using java junit commandline?

Tags: android, gradle, build, build.gradle, android-testing

I have a standard android project where I have an src/test folder with all my Junit test. However I want to run these tests outside of the Gradle build tool, I.e. the person running these tests does not need to pull the android project and run a gradle build. My thought is to build a test aar/jar file and run the tests via standard java command:

i.e. java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-.jar test.jar

Would this work? I tried searching online but couldn't find example how to configure the gradle file correctly to build the right jar/aar to export.